# Is this inheritance schema suitable for building a python package on?

Tags: python, inheritance, package

I've used an inheritance scheme in my python package where all my classes inherit from a base class so that I don't have to redefine copies of methods that get used in multiple classes. Here is the strategy in abstract form:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.update_properties(self.kwargs)


    def update_properties(self, new_properties):
        for k in new_properties:
            try:
                getattr(self, k)
            except AttributeError:
                setattr(self, k, new_properties[k])


    @staticmethod
    def check_integrity(allowed, given):
        for key in given:
            if key not in allowed:
                raise Exception('{} not in {}'.format(key, allowed))

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        ##class specific keyword arguments
        self.default_properties = {'a': 1,
                                   'b': 2}

        ## now update the class properties from defaults
        self.update_properties(self.default_properties)

        '''
        check the integrity of the user input
        (i.e. i'm enforcing the restriction that kwargs supplied by
        a user are predefined in the self.default_properties dict. 
        '''
        self.check_integrity(self.default_properties.keys(), kwargs.keys())


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        super(B, self).check_integrity()

        self.default_properties = {'c': 3,
                                   'd': 4}

        self.update_properties(self.default_properties)

>>> base = Base()
>>> print base.__dict__
output [0]: {'kwargs': {}}

>>> a = A(a=4)
>>> print a.__dict__
output [1]: {'a': 4, 'default_properties': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'b': 2, 'kwargs': {'a': 4}}

>>> b = B(d=5)
output [2]: Exception: d not in ['a', 'b']
```

As you can see this code works well until we start 'chaining' inheritance (Base<--A<--B)). The problem here is that even though I've used `**kwargs` throughout my code, I'd still like to verify user input (I do this with the `check_integrity` method from the base class). Since `kwargs` from `B` are not in the `allowed` properties of `A`, when initializing `B`, `A` calls the `check_integrity` method and throws an error.

My questions are:

1) Can (should?) this code be modified so that classes like `B` can also use the `check_integrity` method and what are the options? I've tried overriding the `check_integrity` method in `B` which didn't work because the error was still through in `A`. I could of course just not check the user input in this class but this seems somewhat incomplete.

2) Since I've already found one unforeseen problem with my design, it would be good to know whether others (more experienced programmers) can see any other holes/pitfalls with using inheritance in this way that would make it unsuitable for building a python package on? (sorry about the more general question here but since I'm self taught, SO is basically my only teacher)

I hope that's clear, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve your problem of method sharing is using mixins. Python supports multiple inheritance, so you can define classes that contain methods to be shared between subclasses. That method will also behave as expected with other inheritance rules.
Example:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def shared_method(self):
        self.dostuff()

class A(SuperClass, Mixin):
    pass
```

Class `A` will now have all methods defined within `Mixin`.
Be careful not to do stuff that will mess with the object's attributes like defining `__init__` within the mixin's methods, to avoid interfering with other superclasses' behaviors :)